# Does it make sense to have the site url as Site Identifier in the DXA publication metadata?

Tags: dxa

Reading through some (possibly outdated) Quick Start documentation for DXA, I came across this example of putting the site URL in the Site Identifier field in the publication metadata.

[image]

In the product documentation, Site Identifier is covered in [Configuring the web application for multilingual websites](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-7D334E4E-72F7-4AAA-B541-7A845E15C88C) and it seems the only requirement is to use the same identifier for all publications that form part of your multilingual site.

Why would you put the URL there? Is there a real use-case in which this would make more sense than a simple string, or is this just a cargo-cult thing that should be avoided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frankly, it seems that the author of the Quick Start guide misinterpreted the meaning of this field. Especially the note is suspicious; for the value of this field, it is irrelevant which mapping is done later.

The field has no meaning other than that Publications with the same value are considered to belong to the same “Site” group.

I wouldn’t recommend to use a URL as value, simply because it is misleading.

Comment: Thanks Rick. It's good to have it confirmed that there's no secret magic here that I should know about.